# Rufus fails to create Ubuntu Live USB

Tags: live-usb, rufus

I am getting the error below while I am making the USB stick to install Ubuntu. I have tried with different USB drives but nothing works.

[image]

Comment: Windows program, likely off-topic here. Try a different USB port

Comment: Try another installer such as the Universal USB installer: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Comment: Rufus has a good reputation. Have you checked with md5sum, that the iso file was downloaded correctly? See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes . You can *clone* the iso file with Win32 Disk Imager instead of extract the iso file with Rufus. Cloning is a very robust process. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb . If still no luck, please tell us which iso file you are using, describe the computer (brand name and model), and finally, please describe *how it is failing* (what you hear and see).

Comment: Check your md5sum. As many people don't seem to realize, Rufus can compute the md5sum: just select your ISO and click on the `#` sign at the bottom. Then check that the number matches the one of the Ubuntu site. If it doesn't, there's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install virualbox on your windows os
2. Click on the star that says new
3. Follow the steps to create a virtual machine
4. Select the iso that you what to write on your usb

Check the iso if it runs on the virtual machine there might be somthing wrong with your iso download.

Here is a detail website on how virtualbox works:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html

Comment: You can see in the screenshot in the question that Rufus has a hash character **#** in the lower right corner of the window for checking the Ubuntu ISO file's md5sum checksum hash, so everything in your answer is an unnecessary duplication of what's already provided by Rufus.